# Heroku throws undefined method `devise_for'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, heroku, devise

I have an app running local, and it works correctly. I've set up devise on it for OAuth with facebook.

When I push the app to Heroku I get this exception:

```
/app/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:2:in `<class:SessionsController>':
undefined method `devise_for'
for Users::SessionsController:Class (NoMethodError)
```

But I don't have this error locally.

These are the steps I took after pushing it to Heroku:

- `heroku run rake db:migrate`
- restarted heroku using `heroku restart` and `heroku ps:restart`

So the problem isn't that I still have to restart my server.

Here is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'pg'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
```

What could be the issue?

### Edit

Here are the first lines of where the error points at:

```
# app/controllers/users/users_controller
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "users/sessions" }
end
```

Comment: Could you add the first lines of '/app/app/controllers/users_controller.rb'

Comment: Are you on the the correct stack? Your dependencies require Cedar. Also, see whether Devise is properly installed on Heroku by running `heroku run console` and entering `Devise.mappings.keys`. This will throw an error if Devise isn't correctly installed.

Comment: @Leito I added those lines. zeantsoi I can't enter the console because it throws that exception when I try to enter it.

Comment: @Ruby Looks like a language worth to have a look at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try running this locally? `devise_for` should be on your routes, not in the controller see https://github.com/plataformatec/devise to make sure you have your settings correctly. You don't need to override the controller, unless you are doing something special with it. If I where you I'll try to do the least amount of change first, and incrementally change it the way you want.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes I had it in my controller AND my routes. I had followed two tutorials, and I got mixed up. The weird thing is, it was working locally...